# An efficient way to transpose a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
x = [ [4, ‘c’, ‘b’, ‘d’], [2, ‘e’, ‘c’, ‘a’], [5, ‘a’, ‘c’] ]
```

that I need to convert to:

```
x1 = [ [‘c’, 4, 2, 5], [‘b’, 4], [‘d’, 4], [‘e’, 2], [‘a’, 2, 5] ]
```

Explanation:

```
'c' appears in lists starting with 4, 2, 5
'b' appears in only the list starting with 4
'd' appears in only the list starting with 4
...
```

obviously this is a toy example, but my real list has about 30 Mb in a flat file.

I was trying with a two nested for-loops but it tooks about 5 hours for only the 5% of the file in my MacBook Pro (8GB RAM).

Is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: have you made an attempt? if not try something before asking for help

Comment: I can't follow what logic is being used to translate x into x1, looks random.

Comment: I can't even begin to find a pattern in here. Why is `2` appearing only once in the input, but 3 times in the output? Same for `4`, but `5` is appearing only twice.

Comment: Looks like he's trying to count what "keys" each letter appears in, where keys are just the first element of each list.

Comment: The letter 'c' appears in all lists, which start with 4, 2, 5.

Comment: `'a'` on the other hand went from 2 references in `x` to `just one reference in `x1`.

Comment: @quamrana That has nothing to do with transpose but nicely picked up. +1

Comment: @pycoder: ah, that could be it. So build a dictionary with the letters as keys, and a list for the first elements (numbers) they appear paired with. Then create a list from the key-value combinations. Which begs the question why this was not using a dictionary to begin with.

Comment: I'm sorry for be late to clarify my question. First element in every sublist is a key, then I need to build another list x1 with each unique letter as a new key with all numbers where that letter appears in x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also managed it in two nested loops:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [ [4, 'c', 'b', 'd'], [2, 'e', 'c', 'a'], [5, 'a', 'c'] ]

d = defaultdict(list)

for group in x:
    key = group[0]
    for item in group[1:]:
        d[item].append(key)


print(d)

# and to convert back to list:
x1 = [[key]+value for (key,value) in d.items()]
print(x1)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'c': [4, 2, 5], 'b': [4], 'd': [4], 'e': [2], 'a': [2, 5]})
[['c', 4, 2, 5], ['b', 4], ['d', 4], ['e', 2], ['a', 2, 5]]
```

A note on efficiency:

On the inside of the outer loop I calculate `group[1:]`. Now, if `group` is large, then even just copying the list might be expensive. If so the loops might be better like this:

```
for group in x:
    it = iter(group)
    key = next(it)
    for item in it:
        d[item].append(key)
```

The efficiency, then, is `O(n)` where n is the total number of items in all the lists. Whether this processing, or the reading of the 30MB of file contents is the slowest, I cannot measure.

Comment: your last approach was the fastest solution. It tooks about 15%  of time less than the first one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @quamrana's assumption of what you actually want to accomplish:

```
x = [ [4, 'c', 'b', 'd'], 
      [2, 'e', 'c', 'a'], 
      [5, 'a', 'c'] ]

letters = {i for y in x for i in y if isinstance(i, str)}
y = [[i] + [sub[0] for sub in x if i in sub] for i in letters]
print(y)  # [['e', 2], ['d', 4], ['a', 2, 5], ['b', 4], ['c', 4, 2, 5]]
```